# ACF Repeater w/ Flexible Content Inside

Tags: slider, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with advance custom fields. I've got a ticket in with them directly but its taking a while. I need to figure this out immediately.

Trying to repeat flexible content for a hero slider where user can add video embed or an image. How do I echo each piece in the loop properly? The content imput in Wordpress is not appearing. The containers are echoing, just no content.

```
<?php
if (have_rows('add_resorts_hero_image_slide', 'option')) {
    while (have_rows('add_resorts_hero_image_slide', 'option')) {
        the_row();

        $herovideo = the_sub_field('add_resorts_hero_slider_video');
        $heroimage = the_sub_field('add_resorts_hero_slider_image');
            $heroimgsize = 'hero-image';
            $heroimg_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($heroimage, $heroimgsize);
            $heroimg_url = $heroimg_array[0];


        if (have_rows('choose_resorts_hero_slider_content')) {
            while (have_rows('choose_resorts_hero_slider_content')) {
            the_row();

                echo '<li class="orbit-slide">';

                if( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_video' )

                    echo $herovideo;

                elseif( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_video')
                    echo '<img src="'.$heroimg_url.'" />';

                echo '</li>';

            }
        } 
 }
```

}

Comment: Is everything in the above code currently working? Like if you add echo 'image'; and echo 'video'; inside the if and elseif, do those work?

Comment: Yes, it is functional. Question I have is how do I echo the HTML with the variable in it. So for instance...

Comment: How would I echo the image variable inside of the src="" HTML?

Comment: What are your field types for the iframe video and the image? is it just a URL and an image field?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The video is oembed and the image is an image ID.

Comment: I've edited my code to where I am with it currently. The content that is input in Wordpress is not appearing as a result of echoing the video or image fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out exactly what I needed. Hoping this answer helps someone else out!

```
<!--ORBIT SLIDE-->
<?php
if (have_rows('add_resorts_hero_image_slide', 'option')) {
    while (have_rows('add_resorts_hero_image_slide', 'option')) {
        the_row();

            if (have_rows('choose_resorts_hero_slider_content')) {
                while (have_rows('choose_resorts_hero_slider_content')) {
                    the_row();

                    $herovideo = get_sub_field('add_resorts_hero_slider_video');
                    $heroimage = get_sub_field('add_resorts_hero_slider_image');
                    $heroimgsize = 'hero-image';
                    $heroimg_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($heroimage, $heroimgsize);
                    $heroimg_url = $heroimg_array[0];

                    if( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_video' ) {

                    echo '<li class="video orbit-slide">';
                    echo '<img class="background" src="http://localhost.com/vail/tier2-hero-placeholder.jpg" />';

                       echo '<div class="container">
                                 <div class="watermark"></div>
                                 <iframe id="heroorbitslider-video"
                                         src="'. $herovideo .'"
                                         width="100%" 
                                         frameborder="0" 
                                         scrolling="no" 
                                         allowFullscreen="true" 
                                         allowFullScreen="true" 
                                         webkitAllowFullScreen="true" 
                                         mozAllowFullScreen="true">
                                 </iframe>
                             </div>';
                  echo '</li>';
                }

                elseif( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_image') {

                    echo '<li class="orbit-slide">';
                        echo '<img class="background "src="'. $heroimg_url .'" />';
                    echo '</li>';
                }


            }

        }

    }

}

?>
<!--END ORBIT SLIDE-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reposting the pertinent part of your code:

```
if( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_video' ){
    //Display iFrame Video (this assumes that your field is a URL field.)
    echo '<iframe src="'.get_sub_field('IFRAME URL FIELD NAME GOES HERE').'"></iframe>';
}elseif( get_row_layout() == 'resorts_slider_video'){
    //Display Image (this assumes that your field is an image field, being saved as an Image Object, and you want to output a custom image size)
    $myImage = get_sub_field('IMAGE FIELD NAME GOES HERE');
    echo '<img src="'.$myImage['sizes']['CUSTOM IMAGE SIZE NAME'].'" alt="'.$myImage['alt'].'" />';
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code to where I am with it currently. The content that is input in Wordpress is not appearing as a result of echoing the video or image fields.

Comment: Change the "the_sub_field" calls to "get_sub_field". the_sub_field echos the data, and you don't want it to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Changed that, still the same. I've double checked the field names. Hmmm...